NodeJs Application can't establish https request using cellular network
I am working on a node application where i am establishing a https request on TWILIO api, when i use cellular network i get this error
Error: connect ENETUNREACH 52.5.19.32:443 at createConnectionError (node:net:1646:14) at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1676:16) { errno: -101, code: 'ENETUNREACH', syscall: 'connect', address: '52.5.19.32', port: 443 }
But when i use wifi the request is successfull with 201 status code. I know that cellular networks have firewall blocking on certain https requests and problem with dns resolution.
But i have to use cellular what can i do in this situation.
except " contacting with the cellular sim provider" and using "wifi".
